# Binding variables seemed to be recognized as methods incorrectly

Tags: drools, optaplanner

drl:

```
rule "adjectFreePeriods"
    when
        $studentGroupAndEduClass : StudentGroupAndEduClass($eduClasses : eduClasses)
        not LectureOfEduClass(eduClass memberOf $eduClasses,
            $day : day, $timeslotIndex : timeslotIndex, period != null
        )
        not LectureOfEduClass(eduClass memberOf $eduClasses,
            $day == day, timeslotIndex == ($timeslotIndex + 1)
        )
    then
        scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,- $studentGroupAndEduClass.getStudents().size());
end
```

java:

```
public class LectureOfEduClass{
    // ...
    //omitted others
    public Day getDay(){
        if(period == null){
            return null;
        }
        return period.getDay();
    }
    public int getTimeslotIndex() {
        if (period == null) {
            return Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        }
        return period.getTimeslot().getTimeslotIndex();
    }
}
```

Here are the exact error messages.

```
Unable to Analyse Expression $day == day:
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: domain.LectureOfEduClass.$day()]
[Near : {... $day == day ....}]
             ^
Unable to Analyse Expression timeslotIndex == ($timeslotIndex + 1):
[Error: unable to resolve method using strict-mode: domain.LectureOfEduClass.$timeslotIndex()]
[Near : {... timeslotIndex == ($timeslotIndex + 1) ....}]
                               ^
```

According to error messages shown, it seemed that the engine took those two binding variables as methods of POJOs incorrectly.
What's wrong with those code snippets? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding `$day` inside a `not` pattern. All the variables inside a `not` (or `exists`) patterns are local to the pattern for obvious reasons. I think that what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
rule "adjectFreePeriods"
when
  $studentGroupAndEduClass : StudentGroupAndEduClass($eduClasses : eduClasses)
  not (
    LectureOfEduClass(
      eduClass memberOf $eduClasses,
      $day : day, 
      $timeslotIndex : timeslotIndex, period != null
    ) and
    LectureOfEduClass(
      eduClass memberOf $eduClasses,
      $day == day, 
      timeslotIndex == ($timeslotIndex + 1)
    )
  )
then
  scoreHolder.addSoftConstraintMatch(kcontext,- $studentGroupAndEduClass.getStudents().size());
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Actually, what I really try to do is  ﹁p ︿﹁q which is equivalent to ﹁(p ﹀ q). But 
in this case, it means that I would have to bind variables in `or` which would result in the same error due to the scope of binding variables. Anyway, the fact of scope differences really helps me a lot. ;) Thank you!

Comment: Yes, but in your `﹁p ︿﹁q` case `q` depends on `p`, so `p`cannot be negated.